# Shortest possible JS code to get ids of all elements of a given tag

Tags: javascript

I want to gather all the ids on a page for `foobar` elements into a comma-delimited string.  For example:

```
<div>
  <foobar id="456"></foobar>
  <foobar id="aaa"></foobar>
  <foobar id="987"></foobar>
<div>
```

Should give `"456,aaa,987"`

The `foobar` elements will not ever be nested, if that matters.

My current solution is

```
[].slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName("foobar")).map(function(a){return a.id}).join(","))
```

**Is there a way to do this in pure JS with an even shorter (post-minification) statement?**

*Edit: In ES5 (aka "plain" javascript)*

*Edit 2:* I was able to shave off a few characters with:

```
[].map.call(document.getElementsByTagName("foobar"),function(a){return a.id}).join();
```

Comment: You could use an arrow function and get rid of the function keyword. [].slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName("foobar")).map((a) => a.id).join(",")

Comment: @Kolby It needs to be ES5; will add to question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't *think* it's going to get much shorter than this:

```
[].map.call(document.querySelectorAll("foobar"),function(a){return a.id})+"";
```

Answer (score 1):

With ES5 I belive there is not much that can be done, however note that the default argument value for the `join` function is ',' so you can skip that and it will end up like:

```
[].slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName("foobar")).map(function(a){return a.id}).join()
```

---

With ES6 you can convert array-likes to arrays using *Array.from*, also you could use a lambda expression to shorten it even more.

So it will end up like:

```
Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("div")).map(a => a.id).join()
```

Comment: Added that it needs to be ES5

Comment: Good call on `join()`.  Added to my edit, which is still a bit shorter than this

Answer (score 1):

Shortest version that I found. I can't find a shorter than this without creating external helper functions. Anyway I think it won't help much.

```
[].map.call(document.querySelectorAll('foobar'),function(a){return a.id}).join()
```

Comment: just the answer I was posting :-). It's actually join(",")

Comment: @Christophe it's not necessary at all. According to [MDN Array.prototype.join() docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join), the separator is optional and it's default value is `","`.

Comment: Very convenient ;D

Answer (score -1):

Collects all 'foobar' and prints id values separated as you wanted.

```html
<div>
  <foobar id="456"></foobar>
  <foobar id="aaa"></foobar>
  <foobar id="987"></foobar>
<div>

<script>

var str = "";

var x = document.getElementsByTagName("foobar");

for(var i=0; i<x.length; i++){
 str = (str=="")?x[i].id:str+","+x[i].id;
}

console.log(str);
</script>
```

Comment: This is longer than my current solution

Comment: But it is pure Javascript

Comment: As is my current solution